# Quantlib - Python: Fixed income curve bootstrapping OIS_handles

Tags: python, quantlib

I see a few OIS_handles set up - eg ql.ESTR(),  ql.Sofr()
As the mkt moves away from LIBOR to OIS, Are there plans to add others
eg CAD: Corra, NOK Nowa etc?

```
if curve == 'sofr':
    ois_handle = ql.Sofr()
    dcount_handle = ql.Actual360()
elif curve == 'corra':
    ois_handle = ql.Sofr()
    dcount_handle = ql.Actual365Fixed()
```

By substituting ql.Sofr() in my CAD curve construction, I get sensible results.
I tried substituting ql.Sonia() since both CAD + GBP trade Actual365Fixed, but the results were less accurate

Answer (score 0):

You can open an issue on the [QuantLib GitHub repo](https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib/issues) to ask for new indices, but they are just there for convenience.  You can already build Corra or Nowa as instances of the `ql.OvernightIndex` class, by passing the relevant parameters to [its constructor].